# MYSQL IF ELSE? What is the correct statement to use (stock from multiple suppliers)

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I have a database in `phpmyadmin` for all my suppliers. I have created a php file that exports to csv on a daily basis the cheapest stock and quantity of each unique sku in the database. At the moment however, it is excluding any item that has no stock anywhere, however, i would like that... if there is no stock anywhere to print 0 for those items.

The original sql statement is (where `name=SKU`):

```
SELECT name,MIN(price) AS minPrice,quantity FROM products WHERE quantity > 0 GROUP BY name
```

I tried already the following, but this does not work as intended:

```
SELECT name,MIN(price) AS minPrice,IF(quantity > 0,quantity,'0') AS quantity FROM products GROUP BY name
```

Comment: You should not need the `AS quantity`. What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error, rather it is just not doing what i intended it to do, due to not knowing the exact statement to use. the AS statements are needed (i think), as this is only a snippet of the whole php file, which goes on to use print $row['XXX'] depending on which row i want it to print

Comment: As a rule, when you post "snippets" of this and "snippets" of that, you're going to get "snitty" answers to your questions. You see you already have two answers from guys that are highly ranked on SO but are still not satisfying your need for an answer. I suggest you be MUCH MORE complete in the future if you need help.

Comment: Ok, no problem, didn't realize I didn't provide enough information to start with. Is there anything else i need to include that i haven't already? Obviously, want the correct code for what i am trying to do, just don't know how to express it in code.

Comment: These mySQL questions are tough but there is a service out there called sqlFiddle that allows you to build your schema and queries in a "community" type setting so others can get a much clearer picture of what you're working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT name, MIN(price) AS minPrice, coalesce(sum(quantity), 0) AS quantity 
FROM products
GROUP BY name;
```

The problem with your query is the `where` clause which filters out all products where `quantity` is `0`.  You seem to actually want these.

I've included the `coalesce()` just in case `quantity` can be `NULL`.  It may not be needed for your actual data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but this is not doing what i want either It seems to be doing the same as my second statement. ie, in the price column, it is bringing up the cheapest price, and in the quantity column, it is bringing up the quantity that is not 0, unless all are 0 in which case it prints 0. What i want is: select the cheapest price, but only if it is in stock, otherwise, choose the next cheapest, but again only if it is in stock. But if there is no stock anywhere, then to print 0. Does that make sense? Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the quantity of the product with the lowest price, try:

```
SELECT  name
,       price
,       coalesce(quantity,0) as quantity
FROM    products p1
WHERE   price = 
        (
        SELECT  min(price)
        FROM    products p2
        WHERE   p1.name = p2.name
        )
```